# Is this sentence grammatically correct -- is the verb informing after the modal verb can in the correct form?

Tags: grammar

When reading about subjects of genuine interest to me, I can spend countless amounts of time learning and informing myself about them.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not on-topic here. Please have a look at our site [tour]. There's also a brief summary of what's on- and off-topic [here](http://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).